# retrieve CMake -G variable in CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

I would like to print out as status message the value of -G"" within my CMake code.
This variable is set in the command line when CMake is called, by default is "Unix Makefiles", you can actually change it in:

-G"Xcode"
-G"Eclipse - unix Makefiles"
-G"Visual Studio 12"

and so on!

is it possible to retrieve the value of this variable within the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is provided by the `CMAKE_GENERATOR` variable.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR.html